# ESLint requiring '.ts' when importing in CRA 2.1 Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I just adopted TypeScript in the latest Create-react-app version, and seems that `eslint` requires me to include `.ts` when importing ts files:

`import spacing from "../css/spacing";  // eslint complains can't resolved path`

`import spacing from "../css/spacing.ts"; // fine`

Any way that I can make the `.ts` optional in imports?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.js` it should work at compile time, ESLint scan time, and when running.

The reason ESLint picks up on this is that some browsers require the file extension for their module loaders.

```
import spacing from "../css/spacing.js";
```

If you are using RequireJS or similar, it is optional - but given it works with the extension across module loaders it is probably a safe bet to use the `.js`.

Comment: Thanks. Importing js files without `.js` has always been fine. Issue is with ts files imports that eslint complains I should end with `.ts`. But I think Im gonna have to ditch eslint for tslint unless they can work together somehow. Still finding that out..

Comment: You might be able to supress the rule if it's a problem for you.

Comment: ECMAScript  module specification does not say that file extension is necessary. Module resolution process is an [implementation-defined abstract operation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule), the spec says nothing about file extensions there.

Comment: @artem - quite right. It's the browser implementation, not the spec. Thanks for the comment.